# Know object select order in python

Tags: python, object-mode

I create Python script for automatic create particle system use any two selected objects. Object 1 is emitter object and object 2 is particle object.

```
objectSelectList = bpy.context.selected_objects
print(objectSelectList)
```

This command give list of objects a user selected but sometime list order is reverse order (user select object A first then object B but list is: object B, object A).

How get correct select order?

Comment: I am not a Python expert, but it appears that you would first need a Python function to actively listen for selection events and to build a list based on that. Every time you select an object, it will be added to the list of selected objects in the order that you selected them. You would also probably need a "stop" listening function so the list stays clean.

Answer (score 4):

**Blender doesn't really have a *"select order"***

The standard method used by blender operators is to use the context object (`context.object`, `context.active_object`) and selected object(s) (`context.selected_objects` in which if there is a context object, it will occupy position 0).

For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> the parent operator makes the context object the parent of all selected objects, except itself. One parent many children.  Similarly for join all like typed selected objects are joined to the context object.

Henceforth for making an operator to select emitter and particle you need to decide which is the  many, ie make the context object a particle and then make all other selected objects an emitter of that particle, or vice versa.

Comment: context.selected_objects won't automatically shift the active_object to position 0, does it? Example in case that logic isn't automatically applied.`active_obj = bpy.context.active_object 
selected_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects if obj != bpy.context.active_object]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bpy.context.scene.objects.active` to get the *active* object (the last selected object)

Answer (score 1):

**Use** `get_ordered_selection_objects()`

```py
import bpy

def get_ordered_selection_objects():
    tagged_objects = []
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        order_index = o.get("selection_order", -1)
        if order_index >= 0:
            tagged_objects.append((order_index, o))
    tagged_objects = sorted(tagged_objects, key=lambda item: item[0])
    return [o for i, o in tagged_objects]

def clear_order_flag(obj):
    try:
        del obj["selection_order"]
    except KeyError:
        pass

def update_selection_order():
    if not bpy.context.selected_objects:
        for o in bpy.data.objects:
            clear_order_flag(o)
        return
    selection_order = get_ordered_selection_objects()
    idx = 0
    for o in selection_order:
        if not o.select_get():
            selection_order.remove(o)
            clear_order_flag(o)
        else:
            o["selection_order"] = idx
            idx += 1
    for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if o not in selection_order:
            o["selection_order"] = len(selection_order)
            selection_order.append(o)

def selection_change_handler(scene):
    if bpy.context.mode != "OBJECT":
        return
    is_selection_update = any(
        not u.is_updated_geometry
        and not u.is_updated_transform
        and not u.is_updated_shading
        for u in bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph.updates
    )
    if is_selection_update:
        update_selection_order()

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(selection_change_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    for f in bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post:
        if f.__name__ == "selection_change_handler":
            bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(f)
    register()
```